# Why can't I access the file I received from the output of "ls"?

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to search for the latest file placed in a directory and I want to read the first line in the file to use as a variable in a command. When I use the variable definitions below and the accompanying line to call Chromium, I get an error that the file or directory is not found, but we see that it was found and if I place an `echo $FILE` between the definition for `FILE` and `LINE`, it returns the filename. In the error message, you can see this.

I have tried a number of solutions, but nothing got me anything but this error. Sorry if I don't define them all here.

```
FILE=$(ls -t /media/presentation/Lobby2/ | head -n1)
LINE=$(head -n1 $FILE)
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk $FILE &
```

The error I receive is:

```
head: cannot open 'onlinepresentation.txt' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you happen to be in `/media/presentation/Lobby2`, `head` can't find the file because `FILE` contains just `onlinepresentation.txt` – the path is not listed. The quick fix is to keep the path separately:

```
path=/media/presentation/Lobby2
file=$(ls -t "$path" | head -n1)
line=$(head -n1 "$path/$file")
```

(Notice consistent quoting and [lowercase variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08).)

However, it's not recommended to use the output of `ls` in scripts, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls(1)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Getting the most recent file is talked about in [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003), and a robust solution would be

```
for file in /media/presentation/Lobby2/*; do
    [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest=$file
done
line=$(head -n1 "$latest")
```

You can even do away with any non-Bash commands and replace `line=$(head -n1 "$latest")` with this:

```
IFS= read -r line < "$latest"
```

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin W. Provided a great working answer.

I ended up going with:

```
for file in $PATH1/*.mp4; do
    [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest=$file
done

if [ "$latest" -nt "$PATH2/video.mp4" ]
then
    cp $latest $destination
fi
```

Thanks